# JSON DataContractJsonSerializer IgnoreDataMember not working

Tags: json, serialization

I'm using DataContractJsonSerializer (my only option for this specific project) to serialize a class similar to this which includes the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute:

```
 public class TestClass
{
    public int Test1 { get; set; }
    public int Test2 { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int Test3 { get; set; }
}
```

My serialization code is taken right from the example page from MS:

```
TestClass MyTest = new TestClass();
MyTest.Test1 = 1;
MyTest.Test2 = 2;
MyTest.Test3 = 3;

MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
ser.WriteObject(stream1, MyTest);
stream1.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
string sContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

But the output I get back always includes the `Test3` attribute:

```
{"Test1":1,"Test2":2,"Test3":3}
```

If I define the class like this:

```
 [DataContract]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Test1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Test2 { get; set; }
        public int Test3 { get; set; }
    }
```

I get back the proper output like this:

```
{"Test1":1,"Test2":2}
```

The class I really want to serialize has dozens of properties and I only want to ignore a small number of them so I would prefer to use `[IgnoreDataMember]` instead of `[DataContaract]` and `[DataMember]`.

Am I doing something wrong with the way I'm using the `[IgnoreDataMember]`?

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, you need to add the `[DataContract]` attribute to your class. Otherwise, the `DataContractJsonSerializer` does not always interpret `[IgnoreDataMember]` and `[DataMember]` attributes correctly.

Looking at your example, the correct version is:

```
[DataContract] // Add this
public class TestClass
{
    public int Test1 { get; set; }
    public int Test2 { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int Test3 { get; set; }
}
```